# How to access object created in serialized way?

Tags: java, actionlistener, createobject

This is my code: where i click the right button of mouse, and select test1 the code create a JLabel and put it in that position.

```
    public class Test extends JFrame {
       int x;
       int y;
       JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("Popup");

       class MyLabel extends JLabel {
          public MyLabel(String text) {
          super(text);
          addMouseListener(new PopupTriggerListener());
       }

class PopupTriggerListener extends MouseAdapter {
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) {
    if (ev.isPopupTrigger()) {
      menu.show(ev.getComponent(), ev.getX(), ev.getY());
      x = ev.getX();
      y = ev.getY();
    }
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ev) {
    if (ev.isPopupTrigger()) {
      menu.show(ev.getComponent(), ev.getX(), ev.getY());
      x = ev.getX();
      y = ev.getY();
    }
  }

          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
          }
        }
      }

  JLabel label = new MyLabel("right-click");

    public Test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Test1");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Menu item Test1");
            JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("test");
            label.add(newLabel);
            newLabel.setBounds(x, y, 40, 10);
                  }
                });
        menu.add(item);

        item = new JMenuItem("Test2");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu item Test2");
          }
        });
        menu.add(item);

        getContentPane().add(label);
        pack();
        setSize(300, 100);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
      }
```

But i don't know after, how i can access that labels (ex to modify their text). I want also to can delete that labels once created if the user click on it with the right button and select "delete", but in the actionPerformed code netbeans don't let me add another actionListener.. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the changes are in the `Test` constructor:

```
public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Change the name here from "Test1" to whatever you want
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Test1");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu item Test1");
            JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("test");
            label.add(newLabel);
            newLabel.setBounds(x, y, 40, 10);
        }
    });
    menu.add(item);

    // Change the name here from "Test2" to whatever you want
    item = new JMenuItem("Test2");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu item Test2");
        }
    });
    menu.add(item);

    // Implement a "Delete" option
    item = new JMenuItem("Delete");
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu item Delete");
            // Get the component at the mouse coordinates
            Component comp = label.getComponentAt(x, y);
            // If the component is a JLabel, delete it
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
                label.remove(comp);
                // Repaint the screen to remove the label
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    menu.add(item);

    getContentPane().add(label);
    pack();
    setSize(300, 100);
}
```

Comment: ok, that works fine!!
but for my purposes i have to make a menu that can change during the time.. Is it possible to make a menu that will be created each time that the right button is clicked? i'm trying, but it doesn't work... can you help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: It is possible to change the menu each time the right-button is clicked, but what do you want to change in the menu?